# PivotTable showing data which I can't find in the data sheet table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a pivot table running off a table in one of my sheets which is showing a value that does not come up as a selection on the filtered column. I've tried selecting all and unhiding rows and columns, and formatting the row and height for all columns as well. For some reason I can't find the data in the sheet but the pivot finds it...

Comment: I’ve seen this when a cell has newline characters (returns) in it. Specifically, I’ve seen it happen within Workday ERP reports. Try expanding the formula bar at the top to see if it is hiding additional lines within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I "refreshed" my pivot table and the data disappeared. There must be a cache of the data when you create a pivot or something.